# How do I share two different associations with the same object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have a belongs to and has_many relationship.

A child belongs_to a parent
A parent has_many children.

However, I also have another way a Parent can have a child, and that's through a join_table I use to create a grouping of a type of parent.

Here's my awful guess at how to do this :

```
# child.rb

belongs_to :parent
belongs_to :parent_group, :dependent => :destroy
delegate :parent, :to => :parent_group

# parent.rb

has_many :children
has_many :children, through: :parent_groups
```

Note, I don't actually use these naming conventions. These were just changed to keep my work anonymous.

Then my migrations look like this :

```
class CreateParentGroup < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :parent_groups do |t|
      t.integer :parent_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_column :child, :parent_group_id, :integer
  end
```

So my goal is to make it that if I type `Parent.find(n).children`, it will return Child objects that are either *through* a parent_group AND any children directly related to it.

Vice versa, if I were to select `Child.find(n).parent`, it would select its parent whether it was *through* a parent group or not.

And then finally, I would be able to select parent_groups and select collections of parents.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you're talking about a join table then I think your schema setup for this table isn't quite correct. It should be like this:

```
class CreateParentGroup < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :parent_groups do |t|
      t.integer :parent_id
      t.integer :child_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

So, now your table `parent_groups` is able to hold many children for many parents.

As for setting up your associations in your models: You can't/shouldn't name two different association with the same name. Ergo you can't do `has_many :children` and `has_many :children, :through => :parent_groups` at the same time in one model. Cause if you access the children by `Parent.find(n).children` Rails doesn't know which association to use.

I'd do something like this:

```
class Parent < AR
  has_many :regular_children, :class_name => 'Child'
  has_many :group_children, :class_name => 'Child', :through => :parent_groups

  # implement a method that combines them both
  def children
    regular_children + group_children
  end
end

class Child < AR
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :parent_group, :dependent => :destroy

  # forget the delegate, otherwise your invoke of Child.find(n).parent always
  # gets delegated to parent_group which is/can be wrong due to data
end
```

I think that's more the way to go...